# String field being populated with a 0 when field calculating

Tags: arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I am trying to field calculate a text value into a string field and when the process is completed, a `0` is being placed in the field as opposed to my text value. Is there something that I am overlooking? I attempted to search for similar instances but couldn't find anything.

Here is the field properties:

[image]

The field calculator value I am attempting to enter:

[image]

And the results:

[image]

Comment: I think we can help you better if you show us exactly what you typed into the Field Calculator. Are you absolutely sure it's a a string field, and not a numerical field with a Coded Value Domain defined?

Comment: I went ahead and added some screen captures in the original post to help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a string value, it needs to be quoted:

`"HV-BUS"`